# clip vector by polygons in python script

Tags: python, vector, clip

I have a big shapefile, and I want to divide in x by y tiles. For testing purposes let's say just 2 by 1. I take the bounds of the big shapefile, create a polygon with smaller dimensions, and try to use ogr2ogr.

```
            with fiona.open(os.path.join(subdir, file), 'r') as ds_in:
            print('primero', ds_in)
            print('bounds', ds_in.bounds)
            minx, miny, maxx, maxy = ds_in.bounds
            pol = Polygon([(minx, miny), (minx, maxy/2), (maxx/2, maxy/2), (maxx/2, miny)])
            subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", pol, 'results.shp', ds_in], shell=True)
            line = LineString(pol.coords).wkt
            subprocess.call(["ogr2ogr", "-f", "ESRI Shapefile", "-clipsrc", line, 'results.shp', ds_in], shell=True)
```

I tried with the Polygon object and with a string representation in WKT, noone of them work.

ogr2ogr is suposed to take shapefiles as inputs. Should I create a shapefile with the cutting polygon, and then another shp with the clipped polygons? I doubt that is efficient.

Which is the easiest way of doing this from a standalone python script?

Comment: I would use minx, miny, maxx, maxy instead of WKT. Get the command line working first, then match the parameters in your script.

Comment: I tried both, and they don't work. My question is precisely how to make them work like this, or, a workaround.

Comment: I could not get subprocess to work either. This is working for me. cmd =  '{} {} {} {}'.format(ogrexe,clipsrc,out_shp,in_shp)
os.system(cmd)